# Setup migration of a Drupal 8 node(s) to Drupal 9

Tags: migrations, 9

Are there plugins that exist that can read a Drupal 8 source by node type and help get set up for a scripted migration? The content type name is different between the source and the target. I found ContentEntity, but I am not sure if this can facilitate the need. I have a Drupal 8 database next to a Drupal 9 database. Otherwise, I assume I will have to build out an entire SQL source plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using [Migrate Drupal D8](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8) module.

If you don't like the above module approach another way to achieve it is to expose content as json in old site using JSON API and use Migrate API to import data in the new site. It gives you the flexibility to define bundles and fields in new site.

Here is another [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123195551/https://antrecu.com/blog/how-migrate-drupal-8-drupal-9) on how to achieve it